# Scrape multiple URLs at the same time in R

Tags: r

Good afternoon,

Thanks for helping me out with this question.

I have a set of >5000 URLs within a data frame that I am interested in scraping for their text.

At the moment, I've figured out how to obtain the text for a single URL using the code below:

```
singleURL <- c("http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?ndc=0002-1200&start=1&labeltype=all")
singleText <- readLines(singleURL)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to scale this up with multiple URLs it gives me an "Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument" message. Here is the code I have been trying:

```
multipleURL <- c("http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?ndc=0002-1200&start=1&labeltype=all", "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?ndc=0002-1407&start=1&labeltype=all", "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?ndc=0002-1975&start=1&labeltype=all")
multipleText <- readLines(multipleURL)
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would be greatly appreciative.

Many thanks,

Chris

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to group multiple URLs in a single variable? Do they all reference a single medication? If not, you could just attempt looping over each URL since you said it works with just one ? I don't have R installed atm, but even if I had, you're working with something very specific and medical-related.

Comment: You should look into iterating over your list instead of trying to store all this in one variable. Take a look at `lapply` and `for (i in singleURL){}`.

Comment: Brilliant -- thank you two so very much!  I looked into the lapply function and it worked flawlessly.